# Counting the number of strings starting with "t" and containing 2 vowels and 2 consonants

Tags: combinatorics, permutation, counting

I generated a list of strings that match the criteria in the title as follows:

```
vowels = Characters @ "aeiou";
consonants = DeleteCases[Complement[Alphabet[], vowels], "t"];

v = Select[Tuples[vowels, {2}], Length @ Tally @ # != 1];
c = Select[Tuples[consonants, {2}], Length @ Tally @ # != 1];

Flatten[#, 2] & @
    Table[
        Permutations[Flatten[{v[[i]], c[[j]]}], {4}],
        {i, Length @ v}, {j, Length @ c}
    ];

words = DeleteDuplicates["t" <> # & /@ %];
Length @ words
(* 45600 *)
```

The count agrees with my math; there are $\binom52$ ways of picking vowels, $\binom{20}2$ ways of picking (non-`t`) consonants, and $4!$ ways of arranging all but the first letter, hence $4!\binom52\binom{20}2=45600$ total words.

Is there a better way of generating all possible strings with the given criteria? I don't see a problem with my method, but think there is some corner-cutting that can be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For ***"counting the number of strings ..."***  you don't have to generate the list of such strings:

```
4! Binomial[Length @ vowels, 2] Binomial[Length @ consonants, 2]
```

> 45600

An alternative way to generate the list of words:

```
words = StringJoin["t", ##] & @@@ (Join @@ (Permutations /@ (Join @@@ 
         Tuples[Subsets[#, {2}] & /@ {vowels, consonants}])));

Length @ words
```

> 45600

```
words // Short
```

> {taebc, taecb, tabec, tabce, taceb, << 45591 >>, tzuoy, tzuyo, tzyou, tzyuo}

Comment: Right, I was just trying to make an exercise in WL to confirm this count :)